# Database Mirroring and Replication in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have configured the mirroring and replication between 4 servers (A,B,C,D).i.e, Mirroring between A to B and C to D, Replication between A and C. The configuration was a success and I am able test the replication(B to C) when I have failed over the mirroring dbs(A to B). The replication works fine after the mirroring fail over but I am not able to check its status in the Replication monitor. When I am having any insert in a table which is replicated in B, it is reflected back to C..it means the replication is working fine.

Any thought on how I can view the status of replication from mirrored server. I tried adding the publisher in the monitor, but no luck. If I check the snapshot agent status, it says could not retrieve the info, same with the log reader agent status.

Any suggestions on this please.

Thanks,
Siri

Comment: This is not really a **programming** but rather an admin/IT-Pro question - should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move

Answer (score 0):

Per [Database Mirroring and Replication (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799.aspx): Add the principal and the mirror to Replication Monitor.

Please see [Add and Remove Publishers from Replication Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152767.aspx) to add the mirror server to Replication Monitor.